# How to run SQLite Query even if Input is Blank

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I am doing an iPad project,  there are 3 tables in UI. if i select row in each table. Sqlite query will take the value from table and run the query. please find my Query below.

```
NSString * str3=tableFou.string4;
    NSString * str4=tableFiv.string5;
    NSString * str2=tablethr.string3;

    sqlite3 *database;
    favorite=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Create view prizeview as SELECT country.name,item_country.id,text.text,substr(text,1,2) FROM country,item_country,prize,item_prize,gender,item_gender,text WHERE country.name = '%@' AND text.item = item_country.item AND country.id = item_country.id AND prize.name = '%@' and text.item=item_prize.item and prize.id = item_prize.id and gender.name = '%@' and text.item=item_gender.item and gender.id = item_gender.id ",str3,str4,str2];
        const char *sqlStatement = [sql UTF8String];;
```

problem is that,  the query is running if i select all the tables only.. but i want results if i select even one table. how can i do that?

Comment: For that you pass with if condition.Try with and condition in and you user for str4 and str 5 and str4,str5 if any condition true query run

Comment: Thanks, but if i have three tables..Then

Comment: you have only one if condition so if you have three or more then use that much and condition in if condition.its just increase two line of code.

Comment: Because if you use single by single it big and complicated for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Try with if condition use with and condition and pass all your str in if condition only.

use your if condition like this.

```
if(([propertyTypeLabel.text length]==0) || ([cityLabel.text length]==0 ) ||( [locationLabel.text length]==0 )|| ([priceLabel.text length] ==0)||([postedLabel.text length]==0))
```

In this like any of text is zero condition true you also use if ant of the table cell is tap your query run.

Comment: i cannot understand what you are trying to say!!!.. can you write an example code here..that helps me better

Comment: Sorry you try with && instant of || I think that will be helpful for you.

Comment: i don't understand the logic if the label.text is 0, then the value in the query will also become zero, in that case how the query will run???

Comment: hey I just show you the example of that how you use condition you not follow the contant of condition use your own table str condition wait i will modify for you.

Comment: Please can you tell me what is that tableFou.string4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't search for empty fields unless the field is actually empty. F.ex. if you search

select * from mytable where username = "";

You won't find it, but if you are ok with the field being empty or whatever result, you must use like instead of =

select * from mytable where username like "%";

or better yet, you can create your query like this, lets say you have three fields to search for, username, firstname and lastname. The code below needs a few more if's and buts, but you should be able to make this work and only add the parameters to where if they fulfill the requirements.

```
NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[query appendString:@"select * from table where "];
if (username.text.lenghth >1) [query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username = '%@'"]];
if (firstname.text.length >1) [query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&& firstname = '%@'"]];
if (lastname.text.length >1) [query appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&& lastname = '%@'"]];
```

Hope this helps